# How to render multipage templates in canvas using fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fabricjs

**Description:**
I have one project in which I'm using the Fabric.js library (version 1.7.22).
I have multipage templates, approximately 10 or more, and I want to render those templates on a canvas.

**Requirements:**

- When the user presses the right arrow key on the keyboard, the next page/template of the current page should be displayed.
- For example, if my current page number/index is 1, I want to show the next page, which is number/index 2 (current page + 1 = 2).

**What I've Tried:**
I have attempted to render multipage templates using a single canvas:

1. I loaded the first template on the canvas.
2. When the user presses the right arrow key on the keyboard, I clear the canvas and load the next page template JSON onto the canvas.

**Code or Example:**

```
// Initialize the canvas
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas-wrapper');
this.Canvas = new fabric. Canvas('canvas', canvasConfigOptions);
this.templateList = [Json1,Json2,Json3,.....,Json10] (multipage template list like this)

// Load the first template
this.curr_page = 1;
const tmp_data = this.templateList[0];
this.Canvas.loadFromJSON(tmp_data.canvasJSON, async (o, object) => {
    this.Canvas.renderAll();
});

// Load the next template
this.Canvas.clear();
const next_page = this.templateList[this.curr_page + 1];
tmp_data = next_page;
this.Canvas.loadFromJSON(tmp_data.canvasJSON, async (o, object) => {
    this.Canvas.renderAll();
});
this.curr_page = this.curr_page + 1;
```

**Question:**
Can anyone please tell me if this solution is perfect for rendering multiple templates on a canvas, or can you suggest a better solution for this? Your guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.